# Gravitation wave lensing

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, gravitational-waves, gravitational-lensing

1. Can black holes act as a lens for gravitational waves?
2. If space-time dips around a black hole or any source of gravity then can the gravitational waves be affected by that?

Comment: The idea that gravitational lenses would also lens gravitational waves makes sense.
You might check out this link.  
http://moriond.in2p3.fr/J03/transparencies/2_monday/1_morning/varvella2.pdf